# Can an ASP.NET MVC model class have a property called Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model

I've just spent quite some time tracking down a defect where a JSON model parameter to an MVC action method was always null. The cause is different to those raised in other related questions, hence the new question.

My action looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendDeviceDetails(DeviceModel model)
{
    model.DoStuffHere();
}
```

And my model class looks like this:

```
public class DeviceModel
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }  // e.g. "Asus"
    public string Model { get; set; }         // e.g. "Nexus 7"
    // etc.
}
```

The model object is posted as a JSON string from a mobile device.

However, the controller action always throws a `NullReferenceException` because `model` is always null. I spent some time verifying that the data is sent correctly from the client end before starting to strip down my model class and build it back up again. (In reality it has many more properties than I've shown here.)

What I found was this: **if the model class has a property called `Model`, you will always get a null reference passed to your action method**. If I rename that property (e.g. to `ModelName`), everything works perfectly.

Is this really as insane as it seems to me? Am I missing some good reason for this restriction or is it just a flat-out defect in MVC? And is there any way to work around it if I really want to have a property named `Model`?

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that the problem might be the fact that you have an action parameter named `model` and a property `Model`. Can you try renaming this parameter to something else and see what happens?

Comment: I just tried it and your hunch is correct. Well spotted! Still seems like an MVC defect to me though?

Comment: Agreed, looks like a defect. At least we know it is not hard to deal with

Comment: Man: "You are so good looking, are you a model?" Woman: "No, I have a Model property, so I'm disqualified."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by the property name (`DeviceModel.Model`) matching the action parameter name (`model`). Renaming either of them solves the problem. So actually it's OK to have a `Model` property in your model class, as long as the parameter you pass it as is not called `model`.

Crazy!